# How to copy/move files between filesystems using UEFI shell

Tags: uefi

How can we move files between filesystems using UEFI shell. If i try:

```
fs0:> mv somefile  fs1:
```

I get an error that source and destination should be on the same filesystem.
How can we workaround this?

Answer (score 2):

> How can we workaround this?

The answer is in the very title of your question:

```
fs0:> cp somefile  fs1:
fs0:> rm somefile
```